# How to partial match url abc/d/e/f to path abc/:rest in Router?

Tags: angular

I am using `@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1`

If I set

```
Routerconfig = [
    {
        path: 'abc/:rest',
        component: MyComponent
    }
]
```

It only matches url like `abc/foo`, but not `abc/foo/bar`.

How can I match `abc/foo/bar` and capture `rest = 'for/bar'`?

Plunker: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/0RKs8gNeFcip6m7Wi9p5?p=preview

Hit `b` trigger `cannot match any routes`.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried myself for this exact use case but I think it will do what you want:

```
Routerconfig = [
    {
        path: 'abc/:rest',
        component: MyComponent,
        pathMatch: 'prefix'
    }
]
```

Comment: I did try `prefix` and it doesn't seem to work. Btw, it seems `prefix` is the default behaviour.

Comment: What about a Plunker to reproduce?

Comment: Plunker example added